# ASIHTTPRequest - Specifying the file to post data to

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest

The following example is given on the ASI website:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Where do you specify the file to post the data to? I have a php file which is expecting the posted data...

Forgive me, I am new to iPhone development..

Comment: Do you want to post local image (UIImage) or you have url for the Image ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont want to post an image, I just want to post first name and last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the url that you passed in `[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]`.

```
NSString *myphp = @"http://www.mysite.com/myscript.php";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myphp];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Comment: Thanks, what does the @ symbol do? when is it to be used?

Comment: It's shorthand for the init/alloc of an autoreleased NSString object.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to post first name and last name then below code doesn't work. I think if you remove setFile method then it should just post first name and last name ?

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
```

Hope this help.